# How to check microsoft live account REST API Token is valid(Expired) or not by using Access Token?

Tags: rest, api, onedrive

I am trying to connect with microsoft live account with my website. I got offline refershtoken and accesstoken with expiration time by using documentation of microsoft.

Now the Question is how to check the token is valid(Expired) or not? Which url is giving the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that returns the `access_token` and `refresh_token` should also contain an `expires_in` value that you can use to calculate how long the `access_token` should be cached. Once the cached token gets close to expiration you can trigger a preemptive refresh.

However, even with a preemptive refresh your application should be on the lookout for `401` responses from the OneDrive API, and use those as a trigger for a refresh. If you want to make a request solely to validate the current token is still good you could hit something like the following - but it won't tell you how long it has left, only whether it's ok at this instant:

> HEAD https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive

Comment: Thanks for your response. May i get the token information like google Oauth2  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<access_token>   response  : if token valid {
  "aud":"8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id":"123456789",
  "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
  "expires_in":436
} expires means  {"error":"invalid_token"}